# Detecting Single OR Double Tap

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, touch

I'm trying to add 2 actions inside an IBAction, one for 1 tap and a different one for a double tap, and I came up with this code:

.h

```
UITouch * touch;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction) button {

    BOOL tappedTwice = NO;
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        tappedTwice = YES;

    // Action    

    }

      else if ([touch tapCount] == 1 && !tappedTwice) {

   // Action  

    } }
```

No errors, no warnings, but nothing happens when I tap the button... Any ideas???

Comment: how are you initializing/setting the `touch` variable? Here's a [link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/double-tapping-on-buttons/) that might help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot capture events like that. The Action is tagged to touchUpInside event so you cannot capture single tap or double tap

Try this link

http://sree.cc/iphone/handling-touche-events-for-uibuttons-in-iphone